# Compare 2 csv files in folder power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to compare 2 csv files. Make sure data in columns &rows match and count of rows & columns match. I want to set it up so can pull from folder and I can refresh when new files are dropped in that folder. What easiest way to do this? Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

[Import data from a folder with multiple files (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4)